# Question mark in URL after closing alert box

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dummy Bootstrap modal with a very simple JS alert meant to be triggered when the submit button is clicked. The code is live [here](http://www.peppyburro.com/site2index.php) and this is what it looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog" >
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="contact-form">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>test</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><p>This is body</p></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="alert('something');">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you visit the site, you can trigger the modal by clicking on the contact link in the top navigation menu. The modal looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there's just one field and a submit button. The button's *onclick()* event is set to alert the word "something" on the screen. This works fine except that when you close the alert, the page refreshes with a "?" appended to the URL. How do I prevent this refresh and where does the question mark come from?

Comment: Wow, at least have the decency to quote a reason if you must downvote a question? Did I violate any rules here?

Comment: The link which offers "code" goes to something unrelated.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev: Nope it doesn't. That's the link where the code is "live"...I have even posted a screenshot. Anyway, Rishat has already answered so thank you.

Comment: [here](www.peppyburro.com/site2index.php) What is it?

Comment: The answer is in my question. Suggest you to read again. That's where the code in live, i.e. can be seen in action. I've even explained the link one needs to click to see the result of execution. Not sure what the confusion is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I thought that it happens because the button has property `type` set to `submit`, so I'd recommend to remove this property completely, and the trailing question mark would probably not appear anymore. But it does.

What really needs to be done is *event default action has to be prevented*. To do that, return `false` right there in the `onclick` event callback function:

```
<button onclick="alert('something'); return false;">...</button>
```

This way you, well, return false, and this is perceived as if you want to prevent further execution of the click event, effectively submit operation.